# Ubuntu Snaps not showing up

Tags: snap, nmap

I noticed when I run "snap find" on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (with all updates) I no longer see Nmap listed.  However, if I run "snap find nmap" it shows up.  Why is Nmap not showing up when I run "snap find" and how many other snaps are not listed or showing this way?  I should also add something must have changed with the nmap snap recently as it was searchable by using "snap find" just a few weeks ago.

Comment: That probably means `nmap` has been dropped from being a "promoted" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy, if you use `snap find` without specifying a package name, it will only output "public, promoted results". The relevant quote here is:

> As long as you know the name of the snap you want, and it is public or
>   your own private snap, you can install it using its name directly. But
>   if you search the store, you’ll only see public, promoted results.